# CMake adds unnecessary dependencies between .o and .a files

Tags: cmake

I've got a project managed by CMake with multiple libraries that have link time dependencies between them, but each of the libraries can be compiled independently of each other.  How do I express this to CMake so that I can build all the libraries concurrently?

For example, I tried this CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project (test)
add_library(lib1 STATIC lib1.cpp)
add_library(lib2 STATIC lib2.cpp)
add_library(lib3 STATIC lib3.cpp)
add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(lib2 lib1)
target_link_libraries(lib3 lib2)
target_link_libraries(main lib3)
```

Each file just defines a different empty function like:

```
void f1() {}
```

When I type `cmake . && make -j4`, I see this:

```
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lib1.dir/lib1.cpp.o
Linking CXX static library liblib1.a
[ 25%] Built target lib1
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lib2.dir/lib2.cpp.o
Linking CXX static library liblib2.a
[ 50%] Built target lib2
[ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lib3.dir/lib3.cpp.o
Linking CXX static library liblib3.a
[ 75%] Built target lib3
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable main
[100%] Built target main
```

Even though I've specified `-j4` and compiling each .cpp file should never depend on any .a files, it's waiting on the previous compile and link to finish begin the next one.  I'd rather see something like:

```
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lib1.dir/lib1.cpp.o
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lib2.dir/lib2.cpp.o
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lib3.dir/lib3.cpp.o
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o
Linking CXX static library liblib1.a
Built target lib1
Linking CXX static library liblib2.a
Built target lib2
Linking CXX static library liblib3.a
Built target lib3
Linking CXX executable main
Built target main
```

Is it possible to tell CMake that it can build all the .o files concurrently?

In reality, I'm doing this in a million-line project with about 20 CPU cores at my disposal (with distcc), so this is a huge bottleneck on my build times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequential execution is probably a consequence of the link dependencies established between the static libraries `lib1`, `lib2` and `lib3`.

One work-around is to get rid of these static library link dependencies. Since you are building static libraries anyway, removing the dependencies will not prevent them from being linked successfully. The executable `main` needs to depend on all libraries then:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project (test)
add_library(lib1 STATIC lib1.cpp)
add_library(lib2 STATIC lib2.cpp)
add_library(lib3 STATIC lib3.cpp)
add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main lib1 lib2 lib3)
```

Organized this way `make -j` builds the libraries in parallel.

If getting rid of the link dependencies is not an option, you can apply the principle ["Any problem in computer science can be solved with another layer of indirection"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirection):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project (test)
add_library(lib1_objects STATIC lib1.cpp)
add_library(lib2_objects STATIC lib2.cpp)
add_library(lib3_objects STATIC lib3.cpp)
add_executable(main main.cpp)

add_library(lib1 STATIC empty.cpp)
add_library(lib2 STATIC empty.cpp)
add_library(lib3 STATIC empty.cpp)

target_link_libraries(lib1 lib1_objects)
target_link_libraries(lib2 lib2_objects lib1)
target_link_libraries(lib3 lib3_objects lib2)
target_link_libraries(main lib3)
```

This sets up helper libraries (e.g., `lib1_objects`), which have no dependencies and can thus be built in parallel. The original libraries link to these helper libraries and also have the  required link dependencies set up. `empty.cpp` is just an empty dummy CPP source file.

Comment: Yes, it is caused by the link dependencies, but my point is that link dependencies shouldn't add compile dependencies.  It's not an option to remove the link dependencies because in reality, my lib2.cpp does need to link against lib1.cpp.  eg. suppose lib2.cpp calls a function `f()` defined in lib1.cpp (`f` is declared in lib1.hpp, which is available from the start)

Comment: I assume you mean `add_library(lib1_objects STATIC lib1.cpp lib2.cpp lib3.cpp)`, etc.  It works, but is far from ideal... I guess it's just a gaping limitation of CMake...

Comment: Fixed. I think it's more a GNU Make limitation than it is a CMake limitation.

Comment: Even though this solution may work, it's far from being that simple. This was my first approach to solving this problem (in my case those are object libraries) but I still need some form of dependency. After all the dependency will quite often come with include directories or even compile definitions and flags. You still need them during compilation but you don't need the library itself. This means that I have to pull out this information from dependency and add it into include directories, compile options and definitions.