# Why doesn't compilation of target executable already start before dependent library is built?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I've set up a CMake project (3.1) with one executable E1 and two static libraries L1 and L2.

All three targets need to compile a couple of cpp-files.
Via `target_link_libraries(E1 L1 L2)` E1 is linked against the two libraries and of course, before E1 can be linked, L1 and L2 need to be built.

But using the makefile-backend and parallel builds (`make -j`), compilation of E1's cpp-files does not even start before L1 and L2 are statically linked - no matter if I use -j8 or -j256.

Can I specify something via CMake that makes sure that the units of E1 get already compiled, even when the (single-threaded) link of any dependent library is still going on?

*Similar Question:*
[CMake adds unnecessary dependencies between .o and .a files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9748864/1743220).
Their solution is removing the link-dependency or introducing a new layer of libraries.
For my case this would mean wrapping the cpp-files of E1 into a separate target (STATIC or OBJECT) L-E1 and linking against that in the actual E1.
But is there no other way?

Comment: Hrm....I feel like this would be dangerous waters. CMake doesn't say that E1 is dependent on L1.a, it says that E1 is dependent on L1. This allows you to support other things (say, E1 is dependent on intermediates (such as configured header files)) of L1, and its dependencies. Components E1 could fail for a variety of reasons if before L1.a is completed...

Comment: That's what add_dependencies(E1 L1) is for, isn't it?
But if it L1 is only mentioned in E1's target_link_libraries, I would not expect unnecessary dependencies.

Comment: Can you show us the CMake-generated Makefile that describes the prerequisite relationships that are the problem here? (I'm curious what CMake is actually doing.)

Answer (score 3):

My current solution is the addition of an intermediate [object-library](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/command/add_library.html#object-libraries) (CMake >= 2.8.8).

So the following script, which does not start compilation of E1's compilation units:

```
add_executable(E1 main.cpp logging.cpp ui.cpp)
target_link_libraries(E1 L1 L2)
```

is replaced by:

```
add_library(E1_OBJECTS OBJECT main.cpp logging.cpp ui.cpp)
add_executable(E1 $<TARGET_OBJECTS:E1_OBJECTS>)
target_link_libraries(E1 L1 L2)
```

This way the cpp-files are going to be compiled as early as possible, without waiting for the libraries L1 and L2 that are linked into E1.

Of course, any compile-time dependencies need to be transferred to the new target E1_OBJECTS.