# How to remove compile dependencies for cmake static libraries?

Tags: cmake

Consider this CMake setup:

```
add_library( A STATIC modules/a/src/src1.cpp modules/a/src/src2.cpp )
target_include_directories( A PUBLIC modules/a/inc )
target_compile_definitions( A PUBLIC USING_A=1 )

add_library( B STATIC modules/b/src/src1.cpp modules/b/src/src2.cpp )
target_include_directories( B PUBLIC modules/b/inc )
target_compile_definitions( B PUBLIC USING_B_WRAPPER=1 )
target_link_libraries( B PUBLIC A )

add_library( C STATIC modules/c/src/src1.cpp )
target_include_directories( C PUBLIC modules/c/inc )
target_link_libraries( C PUBLIC B )
```

Let's assume that headers from `modules/b/inc` include headers from `modules/a/inc`, so any consumer of `B` library must also add `modules/a/inc` to its includes path and also add `USING_A=1` preprocessor definition.

Let's use the `Ninja` Generator (however the problem occurs with any generator, including `Makefile`, `Xcode` and `Visual Studio`):

```
cmake -GNinja ../path/to/source
```

And let's build the `C` library:

```
ninja libC.a
```

Everything builds correctly, however lots of time gets wasted into building `libA.a` and `libB.a` just to build the `libC.a`.

If I change the `C's` dependency on `B` to `INTERFACE`, then `libA.a` and `libB.a` are not built, but compilation of `modules/c/src/src1.cpp` fails because include directories and compile definitions that should be inherited from `B` and its dependencies are not inherited.

Is there a way to tell CMake that specific target should not compile-depend on specific target specified in `target_link_libraries` list (link-dependency should remain)? I am aware that sometimes those dependencies are required (such as if, for example, `A` depended on some custom command generating headers for it dependees), but this is not the case here. I am searching for a solution to specify for each static library target whether or not it should compile-depend on another static library target, while still keeping the link dependency and obtaining all correct compile flags from its dependencies.

Comment: I've seen that question, but the resolution there does not solve my problem. Namely, it solves the problem of parallelising the building of `libA.a` and `libB.a` while building `libC.a`, but it still does not prevent building `libA.a` and `libB.a` when I only need to build `libC.a`. In my case the parallelisation problem from that question is resolved by `ninja` build system.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually it is less ugly than my current attempts so I'll take it :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently I know no way for issue `target_link_libraries` without complete target-level dependencies. And not sure that things will change in a near future. CMake developer's [post from the bugreport](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=13799#c41023):

> Using target_link_libraries has always been enough to get an ordering dependency and many projects depend on this. We cannot change that for any target type.
>
> What can be done without changing semantics is for the Ninja generator to detect when the transitive closure of a dependency doesn't have any custom commands and in that case drop ordering dependencies on it from the compilation rules and custom commands. Only the full dependency of the link step on the dependency's library file is needed. Work on this would be better discussed on the developer mailing list.

[That answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9748864/3440745) on related question suggests to refuse from `target_link_libraries` between STATIC libraries, which removes some unneded dependencies. I have adapted that scenario for your purpose:

#### Non-natural way

Express "compile-time dependencies" with *INTERFACE* libraries. Real libraries will be used only for link an executable or a *SHARED* library.

```
# Compile-time dependency.
add_library( A_compile INTERFACE )
target_include_directories( A_compile PUBLIC modules/a/inc )
target_compile_definitions( A_compile PUBLIC USING_A=1 )
# Real library.
add_library( A STATIC modules/a/src/src1.cpp modules/a/src/src2.cpp )
target_link_libraries(A A_compile)

# Compile-time dependency.
add_library( B_compile INTERFACE )
target_include_directories( B_compile PUBLIC modules/b/inc )
target_compile_definitions( B_compile PUBLIC USING_B_WRAPPER=1 )
target_link_libraries( B_compile PUBLIC A_compile )
# Real library
add_library( B STATIC modules/b/src/src1.cpp modules/b/src/src2.cpp )
target_link_libraries(B B_compile)    

# Final STATIC library.
add_library( C STATIC modules/c/src/src1.cpp )
target_include_directories( C PUBLIC modules/c/inc )
target_link_libraries( C PUBLIC B_compile )

# ...
# Creation executable or non-STATIC library, linked with C
add_executable(my_exe ...)
# Need to manually list libraries, "compile-time linked" to C.
target_link_libraries(my_exe C B A)
```

Becase for executable or non-*STATIC* library `target_link_libraries` uses **real** *STATIC* libraries, these *STATIC* libraries will be built before even object files for such executable/SHARED library.

Comment: I am not sure this answers my question. In my case `C` uses functions from `B` that uses functions from `A`, so there is obvious link dependency (i.e. when executable links to `C`, it must also link to `B` and `A`). However, when building sources for `C`, why do we first need to build sources for `A` and `B`? There should not be a compile dependency between those. There is an [ancient bug report](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=13799) about this, but I don't see how it got resolved.

Comment: I'll update this a bit for my use-case: I'll introduce my version of `target_link_libraries` that will dependency only on `_compile` version of library if target is static library and dependency is static library and for shared libraries and executables it will recursively collect all real dependencies and add them directly. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Nice, it could be a way for make approach more "natural" for CMake use. It seems, that you need also `_compile` versions for `target_include_directories` and `target_compile_definitions` for your case. Meanwhile, I have updated introduction for may post for it becomes a complete answer (not just code). So some comments can be safetly removed.

Answer (score 1):

We've been using the following function to link static libraries against one another without causing build order dependencies between them for several years now. While not perfect, we've been quite happy with it overall.

```
function(target_link_static_libraries target)
     if(BUILD_STATIC_LIBS_IN_PARALLEL)
        target_link_libraries(${target} INTERFACE ${ARGN})
        foreach(lib ${ARGN})
            target_include_directories(${target} PUBLIC $<TARGET_PROPERTY:${lib},INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>)
            target_include_directories(${target} SYSTEM PUBLIC $<TARGET_PROPERTY:${lib},INTERFACE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>)
            target_compile_definitions(${target} PUBLIC $<TARGET_PROPERTY:${lib},INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS>)
            target_compile_options(${target} PUBLIC $<TARGET_PROPERTY:${lib},INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS>)
        endforeach()
    else()
        target_link_libraries(${target} PUBLIC ${ARGN})
    endif()
endfunction()
```

Known drawbacks:

- Boolean transitive properties like PIC don't get automatically get applied.
- The dependencies aren't shown when generating dependency graphs.
- When an error occurs finding a dependency, it often spits out hundreds of lines of error messages, since we essentially defer the checking for the existence of libraries until it has been propagated out to dozens of targets.

Improvements or fixes for any of the above would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the meantime I've migrated my project to use Conan C++ package manager that basically solved that problem for me (I have a separate conan package for each static library and host them on private instance of Artifactory CE for C++).